# Mixing two or more G.711 raw streams

Tags: c#, audio, codec

I am trying to do a real-time on-the-fly mixing of several G.711 raw RTP streams (each RTP packet holds 160 bytes of raw G.711 A/U payload) and streams are all time-synchronized.

I've tried taking the average for each byte in all streams and build a new array of the same size (160) but its values are the average of the original streams, but when playing out the audio, I find it too noisy.

I tried also taking the Max and Min, the mixed output is better, but still noisy ..

**What is the proper way to mix 2 or more G.711 raw streams?**

If I have 3 phones in a conference, each packetization interval (say 20ms), I need to mix two RTP packets from two phones into one RTP packet and stream it to the third one and so on.

BR,
Moatassem

Comment: This is unfortunately not a programming problem, as you appear to have been able to manipulate the streams, but are having trouble with the exact mixing required. You might have better look on other Stack Exchange sites focused around audio such as https://sound.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution already. I had to decode the streams into PCM 16-bit samples, then perform normal average then re-encode the resultant